# Encoded messages in spam

Tags: spam-prevention

My little brother was reading one of those "Win something", "UK Lotto" spam emails on GMail and said to me that it does not even make sense reading the sentence such that maybe it's code for something else.

So is there an app that can translate these spam messages to a decoded message or vice versa?

If so, should I be looking for a special pattern/language or keyword when decoding? [For educational purposes only]

**EDIT:** Did some digging ( *cough* google *cough* ) and got some method called [Steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Alleged_use_by_terrorists).

Comment: I've often wondered if some of those random emails *are* coded messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that these messages are using weird language so as to bypass existing spam filters, not because there is some secret message encoded within them.

Comment: Yip definitely, just exploring the possibility/fantasy if a certain message did come along :)